# Is there anyway to do breadcrumb trail dynamically?

Tags: html

I'm manually adding breadcrumb to my website like this:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <li>
        <a href="../profile.jsp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="../personal-data-sheet.jsp">Personal Data Sheet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="references.jsp">References</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">Reference</li>
</ul>
```

Is there anyway to do this dynamically?

Comment: I assume you aren't using a CMS?

Comment: You should do it in your server side programming language.

Comment: @JamesWong, yes I'm not using a CMS.